# windicss classes doesn't work in Nuxt App

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, windicss

I got some issues with windicss. Classes don't apply on elements.
I've tried to install an older version of windi and it still doesn't work. I've even tried to use tailwind instead of windi, but it's still not working.

`index.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="text-red">e</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

`windi.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'windicss/helpers'

export default defineConfig({
  extract: {
    include: ['**/*.{vue,html,jsx,tsx}'],
    exclude: ['node_modules', '.git'],
  },
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: '#5b0770',
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Remove your `colors` key and set the usual `text-red-500` or try `text-primary` with your current config.

Answer (score 4):

You are overwriting all colors with your current config.

Instead of **directly** setting the `colors: {}` inside of `theme: {}`

```js
export default defineConfig({
...
theme: {
  colors: {
    primary: '#5b0770',
  },
},
```

Consider **wrapping** your `colors: {}` inside of an `extend: {}`.

```js
export default defineConfig({
...
theme: {
  extend: {
    colors: {
      primary: '#5b0770',
    },
  },
},
```

This will, instead of **overwriting** the default theme, **extend** the default theme.

The same applies also to other theme options (fontFamily, screens, etc...)

Please refer to the [windicss-docs](https://windicss.org/guide/configuration.html#example-configuration) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you add a windi css style stop your dev server and start again, it will apply the styles and automatically start HMR for you.

Sometimes I also need to clear the cache `rm -rf node_modules/.cache` and restart the app, also make sure you're using the latest version.